# Entity framework does not assign int? fields

Tags: entity-framework, nullable

EF (v5.0) does not assign a value to a nullable int (int?) field when I add or update a row.

Here is a simplfied version of my code:

```
public class MyTable  
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public Nullable<int> MyInt { get; set; }  
}


void UpdateRow(MyTable currentRow)  
{  
    MyTable rowToUpdate = transaction.entity.Find(currentRow.Id);

    rowToUpdate.MyInt = currentRow.MyInt;

    transaction.Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

SaveChanges works just fine (returns 1, no exception), but MyInt is not updated.  I have confirmed that both MyTable objects contain the desired value.

This occurs for both adding and updating.  Note that I have nullable fields of other types (e.g. DateTime?) that add/update just fine.

Comment: Your hypothesis that EF would not update int?'s is wrong. Just try to replace the MyInt property with a normal int and I bet that that will not be updated either. It seems that you have done something nifty with a transaction object. Probably the root of the problem lies in that class.

Comment: It is possible that I have pointed the finger at the wrong culprit (EF). Most of the underlying code (e.g. transaction object) is generated from templates, therefore the code for one type of nullable field is much the same as any other. Please recall that I have no problem with other types of nullable fields (e.g. DateTime).  I shall look into the generated code (not mine).  

The reason I pointed to EF is that I read an obscure post somewhere about this exact issue and someone said it would be fixed in the next version.  However, I cannot confirm the issue or a fix.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution to update entites in my database:

```
var person = unitOfWork.PersonRepository.GetByID(1);
person.FirstName = "NewName";
unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Update(person);
unitOfWork.Save();

public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            DBSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

Save() only calls SaveChanges().

You need to attach your entity, in your code you are just editing the local variable!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I use the same basic strategy for adding/updating other tables and it works just fine.  The problem is very specific to nullable int fields.  Note that the strategy works for tables with non-nullable fields and nullable fields of other types (e.g. DateTime).